# Automatically chdir to vagrant directory upon "vagrant ssh"

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant

So, I've got a bunch of vagrant VMs running some flavor of Linux (centos, ubuntu, whatever). I would like to automatically ensure that a "vagrant ssh" will also "cd /vagrant" so that no-one has to remember to do that whenever they log in.

I've figured out (duh!) that `echo "\n\ncd /vagrant" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc` will do the trick. What I don't know is how to ensure that this only happens if the cd command isn't already there. I'm not a shell expert, so I'm completely confused here. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`cd` is a Bash shell built-in, as long as a shell is installed it should be there.

Also, be aware that `~/.bash_profile` is for interactive login shell, if you add `cd /vagrant` in `~vagrant/.bashrc`, it may NOT work.

Because distros like Ubuntu does NOT have this file -> `~/.bash_profile` by default and instead use `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`

If someone creates a `~/.bash_profile` for vagrant user on Ubuntu, `~vagrant/.bashrc` will not be read.

Comment: Where do you configure this inside your vagrant configuration? I assume not creating it inside the VM.

Comment: This answer was helpful, but I found the wording somewhat ambiguous in the case of a Ubuntu VM.  This is what worked for me:
1. `$ vagrant ssh`
2. `$ vi .bash_profile` in the directory you find yourself in after ssh 
 - if in doubt first go to the home directory using `$ cd ~`
3. add `cd /vagrant` to the file and save.

Comment: @q0rban has the correct answer: it uses a Vagrant feature made for this, instead of a homebrewed workaround.  BUT, by the way, if you ever want to add end of file if a string "does not" exist, the answer would be: `grep foo ~/.bash_profile || echo "foo" > ~/.bash_profile` where the || means OR, so part 2 only gets executed if part 1 fails.

Comment: To disambiguate `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` even more: https://serverfault.com/q/261802/536173

Answer (score 37):

You can do this by using the [`config.ssh.extra_args`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) setting in your Vagrantfile:

```
  config.ssh.extra_args = ["-t", "cd /vagrant; bash --login"]
```

Then anytime you run `vagrant ssh` you will be in the `/vagrant` directory.

Comment: This is a nicer solution than trying to parse/provision the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  it is the least invasive on other processes in the environment, and speicficly handles the vagrant ssh command.

Comment: BEST answer for 2020+ (might not have existed in 2013 when question was accepted).

Comment: My preferred answer, but note a downside (as of 2.2.14): `vagrant ssh -c <cmd>` or `vagrant ssh -- <cmd>` will *append* to these configured arguments rather than replace them.  So, from the host machine, without this config: `vagrant ssh -c pwd` works fine, but with this config it gives an error: "/bin/bash: cannot execute binary file"

Answer (score 29):

I put

`echo "cd /vagrant_projects/my-project" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc`

in my `provision.sh`, and it works like a charm.

Comment: True, it would be even better if someone knew a one liner that would only append it if it isn't there in the file.

Comment: If you add it to your provision file, add it in the section where it will only run once. If your vm is already set up (and it's not added), run it from the command line. If you're not sure if it's added, open the file in a text editor and check the last line.

Comment: This answer is still correct, but now being 2020 I suggest looking at the Vagrant-Ansible provisioner simply because it gives you a somewhat platform-neutral provisioning technology. (But as always, if something isn't broken don't fix it)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `cd /vagrant` to your .bashrc in the vm.  The best way to do this is in your provisioner script.

If you don't have a provisioner script, make one by adding this line to your Vagrantfile before `end`:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "scripts/vagrant/provisioner.sh", privileged: false
```

Path is relative to the project root where the Vagrantfile is, and privileged depends on your project and what else is in your provisioner script which might need to be privileged. I use priveleged false and sudo explicitly when necessary.

And in the provisioner script:

```
if ! grep -q "cd /vagrant" ~/.bashrc ; then 
    echo "cd /vagrant" >> ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

This will add `cd /vagrant` to .bashrc, but only if it isn't there already.  This is useful if you reprovision, as it will prevent your .bashrc from getting cluttered.

Some answers mention a conflict with .bash_profile. If the above code doesn't work, you can try the same line with `.bash_profile` or `.profile` instead of `.bashrc`. However, I've been using vagrant with ubuntu guests. My Laravel/homestead box based on Ubuntu has a `.bash_profile` and a `.profile` but having `cd /vagrant` in `.bashrc` **did** work for me when using `vagrant ssh` without changing or deleting the other files.

Comment: To disambiguate `.profile`, `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` even more: https://serverfault.com/q/261802/536173. Therefore, I would recommend to use `.bashrc`, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `cd /vagrant` to your `.bashrc` and it will run the command when you ssh. The `/bashrc` you want is in `/home/vagrant` (the user you login as when you `vagrant ssh`.) You can just stick the new line at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it this way:

`vagrant ssh -c "cd /vagrant && bash"`

And you could include it in a script to launch it (like `./vagrant-ssh`).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for 

Answer (score 3):

Ideally we just want to alter the vagrant ssh behaviour.

In my case, I wanted something that didn't affect any other processes in the environment, so we can do something like this in the vagrant file-

```
    VAGRANT_COMMAND = ARGV[0]
    if VAGRANT_COMMAND == "ssh"
        config.ssh.extra_args = ["-t", "cd /vagrant; bash --login"]
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help. Edit the `Vagrantfile` as replace your username with `vagrant`

```
`
 config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
 s.inline = <<-SHELL
 # Change directory automatically on ssh login
 if ! grep -qF "cd /home/vagrant/ansible" /home/vagrant/.bashrc ;
 then echo "cd    /home/vagrant/ansible" >> /home/vagrant/.bashrc ; fi
 chown vagrant. /home/vagrant/.bashrc
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible to assert that your `.bashrc` file contains `cd /vagrant`.

If you are not already using the Ansible provisioner for your VM, add the following lines to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
end
```

And in your playbook, add the following task/play:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: chdir to vagrant directory
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      path: /home/vagrant/.bashrc
      line: cd /vagrant
```

According to [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/261802/536173), I would recommend to modify `.bashrc` instead of `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.